How do I share a Zod validation schema between backend and frontend in a pnpm monorepo?
I am working on a project using a pnpm monorepo setup. My backend is built with Hono, Drizzle ORM, and Zod for validation. I am using the drizzle-zod package to generate Zod schemas from my database tables.
For example, I'm generating a schema like this on the backend:
import { createSelectSchema } from 'drizzle-zod';
import { users } from './db/schema';

export const UserSchema = createSelectSchema(users);

I want to reuse this UserSchema in my frontend for form validation using @hookform/resolvers. What is the best way to share this schema between my backend and frontend within the pnpm monorepo?
Also I'm generating my types from openapi using orval, so I have a nice typesafe TanStack Query.
I have tried creating a validation package, but there are very few good tutorial doing that, and my case is a little different since, I want to include my server app as "dependency" for my package.
I considered using NX but I think it is overkill for my setup.

Have you considered a git submodules?

No, I don't know what do you mean on that

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules - You can put your schemas into its own repo, and have them be dependencies for your main repo or main repos. You can then use your schema repo in multiple places. I feel it would give you the code sharability that you want, without have to do NX.

Thanks for the suggestion, but it seemed like a bit of a hassle. I ended up just creating a shared lib in the pnpm monorepo after going through a bunch of tutorials and docs.
